# Is laziness about stamping passports common at the Bosnian-Montenegrin, Montenegrin-Albanian and Macedonian-Kosovan land borders?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, borders, passport-stamps, balkans

The concerned person, a Dutch citizen, is going on a bus tour in former Yugoslavia, travelling Germany-Austria-Slovenia-Croatia-Bosnia-Montenegro-Albania-Macedonia-Kosovo. They only hold a passport and not a national ID card.

By law, Bosnia, Kosovo and Montenegro are to stamp Dutch passports on entry and exit. Thus, at the Bosnian-Montenegrin border, the person should get both stamps, at the Montenegrin-Albanian border a Montenegrin exit stamp, and at the Macedonian-Kosovan border a Kosovan entry stamp.

In your experiences, is laziness/a lax attitude about stamping EU passports at these particular borders common? I know it's a common issue at the Croatian-Bosnian land border, and we're trying to establish whether the person should verbally ask the officers to issue one whenever they collect the passports from the bus passengers.

Comment: Does it matter?  I've been in and out of Bosnia, with and without stamps, dozens of times.  Nobody ever investigated whether I'd overstayed.

Comment: @phoog Just like with foreigner registration, you're fine without most of the time, but if you get the wrong officer, you're ***screwed*** (had an acquaintance get briefly imprisoned and deported from Serbia for not having an entry stamp at the exit checkpoint. They were Australian). So we'd rather everything is done as per the book.

Comment: On Croatia-Slovenia border your passport can be stamped twice (on exit). So be prepared for weirdness on non-EU border control posts.

Comment: I just drove from Albania to Montenegro and there was a pretty big wait at the border.  An officer waved us to the rightmost lane where there were two officers, one with a clipboard, who may have been writing down the vehicle registration numbers of the cars that passed by.  They didn't look at us very closely and they didn't stop any of the cars that had been sent to that lane.  They certainly didn't see what passports we held.  The car has Swiss plates.  Perhaps I'll be fined if I return to Albania, but I tend to doubt it.

Comment: @phoog Once when I took a bus Kosovo-Montenegro, the Albanians went by the driver's passenger list, and only collected documents for those with non-Albanian/Yugoslav names. AFTER the entry to Albania though, the conductor collected documents to be presented on entry to Montenegro hours later. Equally when I went Macedonia-Montenegro most recently, Macedonian police collected everyone's docs for exit, then we didn't get them back from the driver until in Montenegro

Comment: @Crazydre ... because the entire bus was in transit?  I was in transit from Bosnia to Greece (by ferry from Albania) and back; the departure from Albania on the way to Greece was chaotic, too, as the system was down, but both entries into Albania were pretty normal, as were all the other crossings.

Comment: @phoog Yeah, the buses were in transit Kosovo-Albania-Montenegro and Macedonia-Kosovo-Albania-Montenegro respectively, with tickets only available between the first and last country, but one could easily abandon the trip during a pause stop at a restaurant if one wanted to (though again the driver held all docs)

Answer (score 3):

They may be lazy to stamp any passport, not only EU. I personally prefer to ask to stamp the passport if the border offices forget to do it. In my own experience, I had to ask to stamp my passport at Albanian-Montenegrin border.

While some people suggest that its OK, I would advise always to check that passport was stamped and was stamped with the correct stamp. A few months ago when entering Portugal the border offices stamped my passport with an exit stamp instead of entry stamp. It was pretty hard to explain the Hungarian border officer why I am trying to exit the EU if I have an exit stamp dated a few days ago but no new entry stamps in the passport.